# Unhandled exception for the component "MultiScaleImage" of "Silverlight 5"

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, silverlight, multiscaleimage

I am developing a web application based on "Silverlight 5".

I found a blocking bug related to the component "MultiScaleImage" that happens after a unpredictable (sometimes it takes hours, sometimes minutes) number of zooms of the image.
When the issue occurs the following messages are shown:

- Windows 7 Event Log: Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 11.0.9600.17126, time stamp: 0x53882e30
  Faulting module name: agcore.dll, version: 5.1.30214.0, time stamp: 0x52fdb3c4
  Exception code: 0xc0000005
  Fault offset: 0x003a8d0d
  Faulting process id: 0x18dc
  Faulting application start time: 0x01cf9cf438322755
  Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
  Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.30214.0\agcore.dll
  Report Id: a9de107e-08fe-11e4-b5ce-c86000a4b136)
- Visual Studio Debugger: Unhandled exception at 0x5CCD8D0D (agcore.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFE2E6F2.
- Internet Explorer 11: Internet Explorer has stopped working.

The test has been done with Win7+SP1 with IE11 and IE8.
This bug is preventing me from releasing the application and deploying it to the customer servers.
I can't believe there's no way to solve it nor a valid workaround.

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce this? ..and who says SL doesnt support Win7+IE11?

Comment: It seems that SL is indeed not supported under Win7 + IE11, however Windows 7 SP1 + IE11 is supported. :-) See [System requirements tab](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx) @ChrisW.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the support. You can quickly reproduce it running this test [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_cJA22M0V3MM3N5Ui1MS0NOdlE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Tanis83 ah ok, sorry I just pretty much assume everyone would have SP1 installed by now. I have win7/IE11 on the machine I'm on right now and dev in SL5 all day long, generally building in browser which is why I was curious.